# Copy cell to anoter worksheet with variable row number

Tags: excel, vba

How do I copy the content of a cell to a cell in another worksheet with a variable row number?

I've searched this site and came up with the following code but nothing appears in the destination worksheet.
Worksheet "Koersen" is automatically updated.
Cell A19 in "Koersen" should be copied to cell A3 in "ASML" and when cell C7 in "Koersen" changes it should be copied to A4 in "ASML" and then to A5, A6 and so on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 3 To 1500
        If Target.Address = "$C$7" Then
            Sheets("Koersen").Cells(19, 1).Copy
            Sheets("ASML").Cells(x, 1).Paste
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

As you may have guessed, I'm a complete newbie to VBA
Thank in advance.

Comment: You need to use variables for that. Learn about them here:- http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/variables.html

Comment: As you can see comparing YowE3K's and my own answer, your question is unclear. Please try to better explain your aim.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, although I can't clearly see what you want to achieve..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'if something change in worksheet...
    Dim x As Integer
    Worksheets("ASML").Cells(3, 1) = Worksheets("Koersen").Cells(19, 1) 'make value of ASML A3 equal to Koersen A19
    If Target.Address = "$C$7" Then 'if what have changed is cell C7...
        For x = 3 To 1500
            Worksheets("ASML").Cells(x, 1) = Target.Value '...copy value of Koersen C7 to ASML column A, from row 3 to 1500
        Next x
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is copy `Koersen!A19` to a new row in `ASML` every time cell `C7` changes.  If so, the following code should work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim x As Long
    If Target.Address = "$C$7" Then
        With Sheets("ASML") ' use a With block to save typing
            x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1    
            Sheets("Koersen").Cells(19, "A").Copy .Cells(x, "A")
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```